# Does the word "God" actually mean : Luck ? (Referencing the fortunate Ivri term גד from Genesis 30:11)

Tags: genesis, translation-philosophy, names-of-god

Instead of transliterating the Ivri term : אֱלֹהִ֑ים , English bibles prefer to use the term : גד "God" - in reference to the Creator "Elohim".

**In Genesis 30:11, the term גד "God" or "Gad" appears to refer to the concept of [Luck].**

> [Bereshit | Genesis 30:11]
> And Leah said, "Luck has come"; so she named him [Gad]. (וַתֹּ֥אמֶר לֵאָ֖ה בָּ֣א גָ֑ד (כתיב בגד) וַתִּקְרָ֥א אֶת־שְׁמ֖וֹ גָּֽד)

Does the word "God" actually mean : Luck ? (Referencing the fortunate Ivri term גד from Genesis 30:11)

- Gad גד also has a gematria value of 7. | 7-days of Creation or "Luck"y number

Comment: "English bibles prefer to use the term: גד 'God'" - Which translations? The [39 parallel bibles](https://biblehub.com/parallel/genesis/30-11.htm) on BibleHub don't show the use of "God".

Comment: Does Hebrew actually have (or can it accommodate) the concept of Luck?

Comment: See https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2229/the-origin-of-the-word-god

Comment: Notice how close God is to good, and German Gott is to gut.  Are you going to tell us that English dog came from the Hebrew word for fish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NIV Genesis 30:

> 11
> Then Leah said, “What good fortune!” So she named him Gad.

“How fortunate!”
גָ֑ד (ḡāḏ)
Noun - masculine singular
Strong's 1409: Fortune, good fortune

him Gad.
גָּֽד׃ (gāḏ)
Noun - proper - masculine singular
Strong's 1410: Gad -- a son of Jacob, also his tribe and its territory, also a prophet

It was a play on words גָ֑ד and גָּֽד sound alike.

G1409 appears only twice,
Brown-Driver-Briggs:

> fortune, good fortune ...
> 2. proper name, masculine **god of fortune** (**Arabic**  WeSkizzen iii. 171; גד named often in Phoenician & Aramaic inscriptions, & found in Phoenician & Aramaic proper name

Does the word "God" actually mean : Luck ? (Referencing the fortunate Ivri term גד from Genesis 30:11)

Yes, in Arabic, it means the god of fortune.

Comment: Notice how close God is to good, and German